# jface.preference.FileFieldEditor can't specify a new file

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I'm setting up a series of preferences in my Eclipse (3.5.2) application and I'm having a problem with the FileFieldEditor.  I want to allow the user to specify a log file to print output to.  Often, this will be a new file.  But when I use the file select dialog with FileFieldEditor, it complains that the file doesn't exists ("Value must be an existing file").  Is there a way, without extending the FileFieldEditor class, to suppress this error and have Java create that file if it doesn't exist?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I look the source code of [`org.eclipse.jface.preference.FileFieldEditor`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/FileFieldEditor.java.html), the only solution would be to extend it and write your own version of a `FileFieldEditor`, with:

- an overwritten `changePressed()` method in order to keep the file path even if the file does not exists
- an overwritten `checkState()` method in order to avoid that error message.

So I do not see a way to avoid that `FileFieldEditor` extension here.

Comment: ah that was what i was afraid of.  not a big deal, but i was hoping for a simpler solution.  thanks!