# Allow for non-existent files in FileFieldEditor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jface.preference.FileFieldEditor can't specify a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536362/jface-preference-filefieldeditor-cant-specify-a-new-file)

I'm creating a preference page where users can specify a file to store stuff. When they specify the file it might or might not exist (for a new file they navigate to the destination directory and then add the file name manually) - and that is OK. I try to use the [FileFieldEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fpreference%2FFileFieldEditor.html) for simple property dialogs. However I can't get it to accept an file name that doesn't exist (yet). What can I do?

Code snippet:

```
public class Preferences extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements
    IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

public Preferences() {
    super(GRID);
}

public void createFieldEditors() {
    Composite parent = this.getFieldEditorParent();
    FileFieldEditor mf = new FileFieldEditor("SaveWhere", &Your destination file name:",parent);
    String[] extensions = { "*.xml" };
    mf.setFileExtensions(extensions);
    mf.setChangeButtonText("Pick one ...");
    this.addField(mf);
    }
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Uuups. This question [has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536362/jface-preference-filefieldeditor-cant-specify-a-new-file). I need to extend the class.